# How tty interrupts are sent from pid 0?

Tags: shell, process, operating-system, signals, interrupt

This code prints the pid and uid of a caught signal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>


static void my_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {
    FILE *f = fopen("sig_clog.txt", "a");
    fprintf(f, "Got signal '%d' from process '%d' of user '%d'\n",
        signum, siginfo->si_pid, siginfo->si_uid);
    fclose(f);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("sig_clog.txt", "w");
    fclose(f);

    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &my_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGCONT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &act, NULL);

    printf("Hi, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
    printf("my parent pid is %d\n", getppid());
    while(1)
        sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

After running this, if I open a different terminal and use `kill` command to send signal to this process, it writes a pid and an uid (they are some random numbers and I'm not sure if it is correct). But instead, if I interrupt using `Ctrl+C`, then it writes pid and uid as 0. Isn't the process with pid 0 is the kernel process? I was expecting the pid to be that of the shell. How the shell is making kernel to send signal to the process and why?

Also, apart from `int`, `tstp` and `quit`, is there any way to generate signals through shell itself? or to add custom signal keycodes? like making `Ctrl+K` to send `kill` signal? I saw `stty` command options, I didn't find any.

Comment: There is no PID 0.  This situation must mean that the signal didn't come from a process. Which is the case. TTY signals are generated by the TTY subsystem in the kernel, not by a specific process.

Comment: @Kaz But isn't there a shell process which handles line discipline? And isn't that process that sends signal and not tty itself?

Comment: @Sourav Kannantha B No. It is handled by a TTY driver in the kernel. And it is the driver, who sends the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PID 0. The first PID is 1, which is a special daemon.

If a PID 0 process existed, it would not be possible to send it signals because `kill(0, signal)` means to send a signal to every member of the process group of the calling process.

In other words, a `pid_t` value of 0, as well as negative values, have a reserved meaning in process-related interfaces.

It looks like in this situation, the zero value of `sig_pid` indicates that the signal wasn't generated by a process.

TTY signals are generated by the TTY subsystem (code in the kernel), not by a specific process.

Comment: So kernel don't have a pid?

Comment: The kernel is a library of code shared by the processes. The kernel creates the concept of a process: a collection of resources assembled in a kind of container, which is assigned a PID. The kernel operates outside of that.  At least a monolithic kernel like most Unixes including Linux. There are operating systems in which there is a very small kernel ("microkernel") just for process management and then all the subsystems are processes.